# Git error: Cannot Spawn ~\.ssh

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh, push

I created a repo on GitHub, and wanted to push local a local repo as I have done in the past. I can `ssh -T git@github.com` successfully, but `git push -u origin master` gives me the error:

```
error: cannot spawn C:\Users\Alec\.ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

My GIT_SSH variable is `C:\Users\Alec\.ssh` and in that directory I have my RSA keys. I even tried generating a new key and using that one, just to receive a the same error.

All of my local repos now show this error - I'm not sure what's gone wrong.

Edit: Not that I think it matters, but I get the same issue whether I use the Command Prompt or Git Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GIT_SSH` is supposed to point to the ssh client (ssh.exe in your case), not the `.ssh` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I had installed Putty for a seperate purpose and I am guessing that overwrote my variable? I hadn't changed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well. I thought is was something with the firewall as well, but I ended up re-installing Git on my PC and then it suddenly worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem with you. and all what i do is to shut down my comodo firewall, and that really works. so i suggest you close your firewall and antivirus software. Good luckl.